# Cosmetic/Dental Surgery in Thailand - Resources?

Tags: online-resources, health, thailand, medical-tourism

I'm traveling to Thailand soon and wanted to get some mild dental & cosmetic surgery done. Actually it's not very cosmetic, but some necessary dental work + scar treatment. It should be much cheaper for me to get it there, BUT I'm a bit worried about the quality.

Is there a site where I can see actual reviews? There are lots of sites out there, but none seem to be impartial.

Has anyone here done dental work in Thailand? How did it come out?

What about scar treatments?

Any resources you can recommend?

Comment: Welcome! Please do have a read of the [help], as currently your question is ignoring some of the rules - it's asking multiple questions in one post, and asking for opinions and recommendations. As such it'll likely be put on hold soon. If you can edit it to be more in line with the rules, it'll stand a much better chance of getting a response. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Dentistry in Thailand is good quality.  Many of the dentists in the better clinics are trained and certified outside Thailand in countries like the USA, Australia.  My dentist in Chiang Mai was trained and board certified in the USA.

I don't know of any dentist review sites, but you will find quite a few threads on the subject on thaivisa.com and Trip Advisor.

Comment: Thanks, actually both sites helped. But awesome news - my health plan reversed their decision and will pay for the dentistry as medically necessary. And it turns out that the scar treatment is not something you want to do while on vacation in a place with salty seas.